# Get all the developers of a project using SonarQube API

Tags: api, sonarqube

I know its possible to get all the developers in the system in SonarQube using : "/api/resources?qualifiers=DEV". But I want all the developers for a particular project. Basically I want to get the developer metrics of all the developers for a particular project.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, you are using the commercial SonarSource DevCockpit plugin for SonarQube. In such case, this means that you have purchased a license for it so you have access to SonarSource commercial support. I suggest you to contact it directly.